# How to check if app settings exist in ios setting app

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm working with permissions and I seem to have hit an interesting edge case...

It seems to be that the app settings are not created until, the user grants one or more permissions. I have a button that attempts to open the app settings within the settings app by calling the following code (in an extension on the appDelegate)

```
   open(UIApplication.openSettingsURLString, completionHandler: { success in
       // success
   })
```

The user can access this button before or after any of the apps permissions have been requested.

If the user attempts to open the app settings before granting any of the apps permissions the app specific setting appears not to be listed in the settings app.

How can I programmatically check to see if the the app settings has been created yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with a work around by adding a settings.bundle to the app.

It turns out that adding a Settings.bundle (even an empty Settings.bundle that doesn't specify any PreferenceSpecifiers) will ensure that the application settings is added to the iOS setting app when the app is installed on the device. This guarantees that the application settings are always there.

Right click on the project > New File and adding a Settings.bundle to the project.
Then change or delete the default PreferenceSpecifiers.

For details about the Settings.bundle see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

The settings.bundle I used is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This is clever! You should mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a list of all the permissions used by your app. Say it uses `Photos` and `Camera` permissions. You can check each of these permissions individually to know whether system settings have been created for your app or not.

```
import AVFoundation
import Photos

class PermissionsUtil {
    class var isSystemSettingsCreatedForApp: Bool {
        PHPhotoLibrary.hasUserInteractedWithSystemPermissionsAlert
        ||
        AVCaptureDevice.hasUserInteractedWithSystemPermissionsAlert
        /// And so on
    }
}

extension PHPhotoLibrary {
    class var hasUserInteractedWithSystemPermissionsAlert: Bool {
        self.authorizationStatus() != .notDetermined
    }
}

extension AVCaptureDevice {
    class var hasUserInteractedWithSystemPermissionsAlert: Bool {
        self.authorizationStatus(for: .video) != .notDetermined
    }
}
```

This requires some maintenance as new permissions are added to the app. Solves the purpose without using any private APIs though.

Comment: I tried the approach, unfortunately I ran into an issue where the user could be presented with the location Permissions alert, and chose to deny that permission, and after that the application would still not be listed in the ios settings app. So it does not appear to be true that this works in general, since in that case the locations permissions is not .notDeteremed any more it is .denied.
And thanks for you help anyways this was a good suggestion.